# Каким образом return возвращает значение не взаимодействуя с ним?

Tags: c#, методы

Есть следующий метод. Необходим для преобразования идеального дерева в дерево поиска. После всех манипуляций, в последнем условии присваивается результат, но он никак не сохраняется в переменную root. Не смотря на это в отладке я вижу, что root возвращает значение, которое было сохранено в anc.left или anc.right в зависимости от результата. Каким образом это происходит?

```
    public static Tree AddSearchTree(Tree root, int element)//создание элемента дерева поиска 
    {
        if (root == null)//если дерево пустое 
            return MakePoint(element);
        Tree cur = root;//текущие элемент 
        Tree anc = null;//предок 
        bool ok = false;//флажок 
        while (cur != null && !ok)//пока текущие элемент не null 
        {
            anc = cur;//переходим по элементам 
            if (element == cur.data)
                ok = true;//если значения элементов совпали, не записываем один и тот же 
            else
            {
                if (element < cur.data)//если меньше - в левую ветку 
                    cur = cur.left;
                else
                    cur = cur.right;//если больше - в правую ветку 
            }
        }
        if (ok)
            return root;
        cur = MakePoint(element);
        if (cur.data < anc.data)
            anc.left = cur;
        else
            anc.right = cur;
        return root;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что объекты передаются по ссылке. Когда ты создаешь `Tree cur = root`, у тебя не копируется сам объект `root`, а передается лишь ссылка на него. Тем самым и через `root`, и через `cur`, у тебя доступ к одной области памяти. Чтоб это избежать, тебе надо сделать конструктор копирования, либо любым другим образом именно скопировать объект со всем его содержимым.

Comment: Эм.. Зачем? И ещё, в шарпе нет конструкторов копирования.

Comment: @Qwertiy, `Clone` же есть, можно его реализовать

Comment: @АндрейNOP, я в курсе... Лучше скажи, зачем копирование в построении дерева, потому что я не вижу причин там что-либо копировать.

Comment: @Qwertiy, не скажу :P

Comment: Я указал на твою проблему и указал на способ ее решения. Я даже не разбирал что твой код делает, мне это не интересно. Вопрос примитивный уровня первой недели изучения ООП.

Comment: Более того, твое утверждение, что "в шарпе нет конструкторов копирования" это чушь. `public Tree(Tree prev) {this.param = prev.param;}`

Answer (score 1):

В предыдущем ответ все было правильно сказано. Для более быстрой работы в c# в методы передаются не сами объекты, а их копии.

```
AddSearchTree(Tree root, int element){...}
```

Другими словами переменная root является не изначальным объектом, а его копией. Ваши изменения будут сохранятся в изначальном объекте пока вы работаете со свойствами его копии

```
...
else
            {
                if (element < cur.data)//если меньше - в левую ветку 
                    cur = cur.left;
                else
                    cur = cur.right;//если больше - в правую ветку 
            }
...
cur = MakePoint(element);
        if (cur.data < anc.data)
            anc.left = cur;
        else
            anc.right = cur;
```

В данных местах вы перестаете ссылаться на копию изначального объекта. А раз объект другой, то и другой участок памяти. Когда вы присваиваете переменной root значение другого объекта, то вы теряете связь с изначальным.

В вашем случае можно передавать в метод параметры по ссылке

```
AddSearchTree(ref Tree root, int element){...}
```

Или присваивать результат метода к изначальной переменной

```
...
root = AddSearchTree(Tree root, int element);
...
```

Здесь более подробно о передаче параметров 
https://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/charp_theory/level5/5_9.php
https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.9.php

Comment: _"Для более быстрой работы в c# в методы передаются не сами объекты, а их копии"_ - что за бред?